# Linestring segment completition?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, linestring, filling

I just extracted some river paths from some old maps I acquired a few weeks ago, they seem accurate enough and will be very interesting to put against my theoretical mapping calculated by using the mnt.

The little issue I have is as follows: Even if I am satisfied by what was extracted and turned into a linestring by SAGA, a lot of gaps are still present. This is due to the fact that some bridges and roads overlap with the rivers and the accuracy of my very own pixel extraction. I am looking for the best way to fill those gaps, using Postgres if possible.

I tried a few things already but it wasn't very useful or accurate. I tried using centroids, startpoints, endpoints combined with Delaunay triangulation and Voronoi polygons. It did simplify the geometry and filled **some** of the gaps but the query was very complex and convoluted, even after optimization it took a lot of time to do anything even on only a few segments. That and I don't think I am going about it the right way.